# How to check if a variable should goto a blob data-type

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

I have a generic function of php to insert data into mysql.

```
public static function query($sql) {
    self::CONNECT ();


    $numargs = func_num_args ();
    $arg_list = func_get_args ();
    //start from 1st parameter as 0th parameter is the query

    for($i = 1; $i < $numargs; $i ++) {
        //echo $arg_list[$i]." - ";
        if (is_int ( $arg_list [$i] )) {
            $query->bindParam ( $i, $arg_list [$i], PDO::PARAM_INT );
        } else {
            $query->bindParam ( $i, $arg_list [$i], PDO::PARAM_STR );
        }
    }


    $query->execute ();

    return $query;
}
```

Here I was wondering how can I check if the given argument is a for a `BLOB` data type? So that I can give it `PDO::PARAM_LOB` while calling `bindParam`

Comment: It would usually be dictated by the data type of the column into which the data is about to be inserted, which would be known to a less generic function...

Comment: I second eggyyal. Use a stored procedure to handle your updates. In the stored procedure, you can check the field type and handle accordingly. 

Otherwise you might also want to check the data for EOF or any other file markers that are unique to file streams or BLOBs. Good luck.